# Where is my nginx being configured? Changing nginx.conf still brings me to the 'Welcome to nginx' page

Tags: nginx

I'm running Ubuntu and have nginx installed. I originally had it configured and it was working as expected. I used a script ([located here](https://github.com/JasonGiedymin/nginx-init-ubuntu)) to fix my nginx start and stop scripts. After I did this, I noticed my website now displays the nginx 'Welcome to nginx!' page without me changing my conf file. Now I can't get nginx to display my site. I can't find what is telling nginx to serve the file located at /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html. I've checked configuration files located in my sites-enabled and sites-available directory. I don't know where else to look. I've tried some grep-ing but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rewrite the nginx.conf in the source code folder of nginx and install it first, it will be copied to `/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` (without specially modifying the `configure` in the source code folder).

But when you do this secondly, the `nginx.conf` in the source code folder will be copied to `/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf.default`,and it usually doesn't work unless you use `nginx -c /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf.default` to assign its configure file every time.

There is a line `NGINX_CONF_FILE="/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf"` in your script above, which indicates the configure file clearly.

To handle this, I suggest to rewrite `/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` (not the one in the folder of source code) instead.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the answer.

Comment: I don't have this folder /usr/local/nginx forget about nginx.conf inside it. But I don have a nginx.conf inside /etc/ngnix/nginx.conf ? Is it the same file ?

Comment: @SarasArya "The way nginx and its modules work is determined in the configuration file. By default, the configuration file is named nginx.conf and placed in the directory `/usr/local/nginx/conf`, `/etc/nginx`, or `/usr/local/etc/nginx`." --[Beginner’s Guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html)